# Satisfy dependencies on autoremove

Tags: apt, manpage

Based on **man apt-get** for **autoremove** we got

> autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
>   installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no
>   more needed.

Can any one tell me what is **satisfy dependencies** meaning ? I see this command widly used also in somewhere which we do not instsall any thing. Ok what is autoremove realy is and why it used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dependency is a package required by another package to complete its own functionality. There are two popular packaging mechanisms:

- [debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging)
- [RPM](http://www.rpm.org/%E2%80%8E)

Both these mechanisms use the concept of dependencies. Ubuntu uses debian packaging.

If A and B are two packages and A is a dependency for B, satisfying dependency means installing the version of package A as required by B. So, if you just `remove` B, A will still be there on your system. If you do `sudo apt-get autoremove` and no other package requires A, then A will be removed. However, note that if you remove A, B will be automatically removed since B depended on A.

Answer (score 2):

If the package `pkg1` depends on the package `pkg2` and you install `pkg1` then the package manager will automatically install `pkg2` to *satisfy this dependency*.

If you later remove `pkg1` again, the package manager will *not* automatically remove `pkg2`.

`apt-get autoremove` will remove packages like `pkg2` that got installed not because you asked for it but because you installed and later removed another package that depends on them.